# My IIS Log doesn't show visitor IP

Tags: iis-7

My IIS 7.5 Log doesn't show visitor IPs some times. 
Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a result of application request routing in iis.

Take a look at this article for a possible resolution:

http://blogs.iis.net/anilr/archive/2009/03/03/client-ip-not-logged-on-content-server-when-using-arr.aspx

You may also be able to add the REMOTE_ADDR into server variables under URL rewrite.  This can help if you are using multiple servers (in which case you need to add the remote_addr to each server).

Lastly, also remember that proxy hosts wont return the end client but just the proxy's ip.